# Places in Tanach where Yaakov & Eliyahu are spelled different than usual

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, eliyahu-hanavi, spelling-variants, bechukosai, jacob

Rashi in Parshas Bechukosai פרק כו פסוק מב says there are 5 places that Yaakov is spelled with a **vav** like this יעקוב & Eliyahu is spelled without a **vav** like this אליה.

The first full spelling of Yaakov that I know of is the above Pasuk. I know of one place where Eliyahu is spelled missing the **vav**. That is in מלאכי פרק ג פסוק כג. Where are the other 4 places in Tanach where Yaakov & Eliyahu are spelled differently than usual?

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct :)

Answer (score 9):

**Yaakov with a vav:**

Leviticus ([26:42](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.26.42?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)), Jeremiah ([30:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.30.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), ([33:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.33.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), ([46:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.46.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), ([51:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.51.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

**Eliyahu without a vav:**

II Kings ([1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), ([1:4](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.1.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), ([1:8](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.1.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), ([1:12](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.1.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), Malachi ([3:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.3.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: Interesting how four of each are in the same sefer, with just one outlier. Coincidence?

Comment: No idea. I was wondering the same thing.